# Rails : How to model User, Patient and Doctor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am building a doctor appointment web application much like : practo and zocdoc.

I have a patient with his personal information name and all the date, a patient can book an appointment with any doctor.

A doctor with his personal information much like the patient and his professional data like education experience etc ...

َA doctor will have a very different dashboard than the patient to manage his appointments, calendar, patients, rapports and more, also the doctor will have to be confirmed by the administration for his account to be visible.

I am very confused about how to handle the authentication using devise.

I was thinking of having a User devise model that belongs to patient and belongs to a doctor.

Both Patient and Doctor has_one :user. Then I will have two registrations pages one for doctor and the other for a patient to pass the type attribute.

Or Using two devise models one for patient and other for doctor.

I tried using polymorphic association but I think it's not stable solution.
I need guidance about the best approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project, I created 2 devise models and, maybe because of my lake of experience, I rewrote most of the functionalities I needed. IMO Devise is like scaffolding, it's nice at the beginning but when you have change your logic it's getting bad

What I achieved : one devise model, for my 'doctors', because I am too lazy to avoid using current_user in my admin

A lot of has_many :through, KISS (Keep it simple, stupid)

My experience, after 3 months on this model

Grégoire